# making smtp class for windows store apps and windows phone apps

Tags: .net, sockets, smtp, windows-store-apps, windows-phone

i am a 4th year student and  want to make a smtp class for windows store apps and/or for windows phone apps as my minor project.
i have not build any library for .net yet, and have no experience of socket programming.
I dont have any idea how to do it and what skills are required to build this,
so anyone please tell me exactly what are the things i will be required to do ?
and knowledge of which topics will be required ?
Do i need to do the socket programming?
do i need to build a mail server?
Or if you think this idea is totally crap for minor project?

Comment: In .NET mail is available through the System.Net.Mail namespace, so you don't have to build this yourself.  The only issue is: I don't know if that is supported by windows phone and windows store.

Comment: it is not supported by windows phone and windows store Brian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't done any socket programming I propose to learn first the basics of socket programming in C#. A start could be the book C# Network Programming http://www.amazon.de/C-Network-Programming-Richard-Blum/dp/0782141765. This book contains also a chapter about SMTP.

As you said you want to build this library for Windows Phone I assume you only need a client to send mails to a server. A mail server inside a Windows Phone would not make a lot of sense...

But to build a library with a useful interface you should have some experience in using the Protocol. So build first a small example client for Windows Form, refactor it, test it (with different mail servers, if possible) and with the experiences you've made create your SMTP library.

tl;dr:

1. learn the socket basics
2. build a first mail client
3. think about the interface and create your library